# grunt-contrib-uglify how to add contributors to banner

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

I am trying to use grunt-contrib-uglify to add the package.json contributors to the output banner.

Is it possible to iterate through the contributors array?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```js
var banner = '/**\n' +
  ' * YourProject.js - v<%= pkg.version %> - build <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss") %>\n' +
  ' * Contributors: <%= pkg.contributors.join(", ") %>\n' +
  ' * Copyright (c) 2013 Your Name; Licensed MIT\n' +
  ' */\n';
```

Using Array.join, there is no need to iterate over the array.

Comment: ah nice, elegant to be fair

Comment: For me this outputs "Contributors: [object Object]"

Comment: @dude try this instead: `<%= pkg.contributors.map( x => x.author ).join(", ") %>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.  works a treat.

```
var contributors = grunt.template.process('<% _.forEach( contributors, function(contributor) { %>\n    * <%= contributor.name %> <<%= contributor.email %>><% }); %>', {data{'contributors': pkg.contributers}});
```